# How can a Makefile replacement pattern produce more than one output per input?

Tags: gnu-make

In our code base we have a code generator which takes `foo.xyz` and produces two source files `foo-in.c` and `foo-out.c`.

In an application's `Makefile` I would like to list the sources as:

```
SOURCES=main.c gadget.c foo.xyz
```

Then the corresponding `OBJECTS` variable should expand to:

```
OBJECTS=main.o gadget.o foo-in.o foo-out.o
```

but I'm unable to find whether it is possible to do this expansion generically using GNU Make. The common `$(SOURCES:.c=.o)` replacement pattern replaces a single source file with a single object file.

How can I write a substitution pattern which will produce multiple output files per input file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, while writing the question I found a usable solution.

```
SOURCES=main.c gadget.c foo.xyz
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(filter %.c,$(SOURCES))) \
    $(patsubst %.xyz,%-in.o,$(filter %.xyz,$(SOURCES))) \
    $(patsubst %.xyz,%-out.o,$(filter %.xyz,$(SOURCES)))

app: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)

%-in.c %-out.c: %.xyz
    # Very special codegen rule
    touch $(patsubst %.xyz,%-in.c,$<)
    touch $(patsubst %.xyz,%-out.c,$<)
```

When converting from `$(SOURCES)` to `$(OBJECTS)` use two separate `patsubst` calls to the filteres out `.xyz` files. This way, both the `%-in.o` and `%-out.o` files ends up in the object list.

Another solution could be to create an intermediate sources list using the same trick but substituting `xyz` with the corresponding `-in.c` and `-out.c` patterns. Then the objects list could be created in the traditional way. An added benefit of this method would be that creating a rule which generates all source code files is trivial.

Comment: Another option is to use `$(foreach S,$(filter %.xyz,$(SOURCES)),$S-in.o $S-out.o)` rather that two substitutions.

Comment: @MadScientist That's an even better suggestion. Feel free to post it as an answer so I can accept it as the solution :-)